# Tree/array mashup

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, lookup

I'm currently trying to prove a data structure which I've created to speed up lookups for integral keys. The specific case I have in mind has the following usage case:

1. At start is populated with n number of items (where n can be from 1 to thousands), and the specific key is actually an `unsigned int`.
2. The critical path in the code requires a lookup based on this key.

I've tried the following:

1. sorted `vector` with binary search
2. `std::map`
3. `boost::unordered_map`

And now this tree. I've found through profiling that the following holds

1. If every item looked up exists, then `unordered_set` is quicker than `std::map` which is quicker than sorted vector
2. If the number of successful lookups for the search set is low, then `std::map` is quicker than `unordered_set` (I guess the hash overhead is higher for failure case)

With this tree, I've found that it's quicker in all cases, but what I would like is some critique on the approach - are there any further optimisations that I am missing for example, and here is the tree:

```
/** Copyright: Nim 2011 */
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class tree
{
public:
  typedef ValueType        value_type;
  typedef ValueType&       reference;
  typedef ValueType const& const_reference;
  typedef KeyType          key_type;
  typedef ValueType*       iterator;
  typedef ValueType const* const_iterator;

private:
  static const size_t MAX_SIZE = 256;

  typedef unsigned char index_type;

  struct node
  {
    node() : _cKey(), _cValue(), _vNodes() {}

    ~node()
    {
      cleanup();
    }

    void add(key_type index, key_type key, const_reference value)
    {
      if (!index)
      {
        _cKey = key;
        _cValue.reset(new value_type(value));
        return;
      }
      // get the lsb
      index_type lsb = index & 0xff;
      if (!_vNodes)
      {
        _vNodes = new node*[MAX_SIZE]();
        _vNodes[lsb] = new node();
      }
      else if (!_vNodes[lsb])
        _vNodes[lsb] = new node();

      _vNodes[lsb]->add(index >> 8, key, value);
    }

    iterator find(key_type index, key_type key)
    {
      if (_cKey == key)
        return _cValue.get();

      if (_vNodes)
      {
        // get the lsb
        index_type lsb = index & 0xff;
        if (_vNodes[lsb])
          return _vNodes[lsb]->find(index >> 8, key);
      }
      return 0;
    }

    const_iterator find(key_type index, key_type key) const
    {
      if (_cKey == key)
        return _cValue.get();

      if (_vNodes)
      {
        // get the lsb
        index_type lsb = index & 0xff;
        if (_vNodes[lsb])
          return _vNodes[lsb]->find(index >> 8, key);
      }
      return 0;
    }

    void optimize()
    {
      if (_vNodes)
      {
        // first see how many nodes we have
        size_t count = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
          count += (_vNodes[i] != 0);
        switch(count)
        {
          case 0: return; // nothing to optimize
          case 1: pullup(); break;// we could pull up
          default:
          {
            // means we have more than one node at this level, so optimize each
            for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
              if (_vNodes[i])
                _vNodes[i]->optimize();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void pullup()
    {
      // try to pullup a leaf node
      for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
        if (_vNodes[i])
        {
          // if we manage to pullup, then cleanup the nodeset at this level
          if (_vNodes[i]->pullup(_cKey, _cValue))
            cleanup();
          break;
        }
    }

    bool pullup(key_type& key, boost::shared_ptr<value_type>& value)
    {
      if (!_vNodes)
      {
        // this is a leaf node -
        key = _cKey;
        value = _cValue;
        return true;
      }
      // cannot pull up at this level
      // see whether we can pull up from levels below
      size_t count = 0;
      for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
        count += (_vNodes[i] != 0);
      switch(count)
      {
        case 0:
        {
          // this is a leaf node -
          key = _cKey;
          value = _cValue;
          return true;
        }
        case 1:
        {
          for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
            if (_vNodes[i])
              // if we manage to pullup, then cleanup the nodeset at this level
              return _vNodes[i]->pullup(key, value);
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          // means we have more than one node at this level so cannot pullup
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    void print(size_t index, std::ostream& str)
    {
      str << "<node i='" << index << '\'';
      if (_cValue)
        str << " key='" << _cKey << "' value='" << *_cValue << "'";
      str << '>' << std::endl;

      if (_vNodes != 0)
        for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
          if (_vNodes[i])
            _vNodes[i]->print(i, str);

      str << "</node>";      
    }

    void cleanup()
    {
      if (_vNodes)
      {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
          if (_vNodes[i])
            delete _vNodes[i];
        delete[] _vNodes;
        _vNodes = 0;
      }
    }

    key_type _cKey;
    boost::shared_ptr<value_type> _cValue;
    node** _vNodes;
  };

public:

  tree() : _vNodes() {}

  ~tree()
  {
    if (_vNodes != 0)
    {
      for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
        if (_vNodes[i])
          delete _vNodes[i];
      delete[] _vNodes;
      _vNodes = 0;
    }
  }

  iterator end() { return 0; }
  const_iterator end() const { return 0; }

  void add(key_type key, const_reference value)
  {
    // get the lsb
    unsigned char lsb = key & 0xff;
    if (!_vNodes)
    {
      _vNodes = new node*[MAX_SIZE]();
      _vNodes[lsb] = new node();
    }
    else if (!_vNodes[lsb])
      _vNodes[lsb] = new node();

    _vNodes[lsb]->add(key >> 8, key, value);
  }

  iterator find(key_type key)
  {
    if (_vNodes)
    {
      // get the lsb
      index_type lsb = key & 0xff;
      if (_vNodes[lsb])
        return _vNodes[lsb]->find(key >> 8, key);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  const_iterator find(key_type key) const
  {
    if (_vNodes)
    {
      // get the lsb
      index_type lsb = key & 0xff;
      if (_vNodes[lsb])
        return _vNodes[lsb]->find(key >> 8, key);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void optimize()
  {
    if (_vNodes )
      // optmize each root node
      for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
        if (_vNodes[i])
          _vNodes[i]->optimize();
  }

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, tree const& t)
  {
    str << "<?xml version='1.0'?>" << std::endl;
    if (!t._vNodes)
      return str << "<tree/>" << std::endl;
    str << "<tree> " << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
      if (t._vNodes[i])
        t._vNodes[i]->print(i, str);
    return str << "</tree> " << std::endl;    
  }

private:
  node** _vNodes;
};
```

Some salient points:

1. I don't need the container to be iterable - all I want is the fastest possible lookups
2. I don't care about insertion performance as it's a start up cost
3. I've added an `optimize` method to "prune" the tree and this works nicely, however the performance difference between a pruned and a normal tree is negligible.
4. Yes, I've considered `boost::scoped_array`.
5. I am considering using a `std::vector<node*>` rather than `node**`, I find the pointer syntax strangely appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few points (caveat: I'm not a C++ expert).

1. Comparing structured (i.e., non-scalar) keys is often the most expensive part of doing a search; it is usually worth searching first on an integer hash of the key.  This way you only need to do integer comparisons for the most part.
2. I am AMAZINGLY surprised that binary search on a sorted array doesn't beat the pants off everything else.  Binary search is vastly simpler than anything else and has optimal pruning.  I seriously suspect your results here are to do with issue (1) above.
3. You don't say how much your results differed in your experiments.  If the differences are small, it probably isn't worth rolling your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, 1) yes, which is why unordered_map (which uses a hashing) suffers, hashing is actually more expensive than four right shifts (which is worst case with the above tree). 2) Well, a binary search on a sorted array is really no different to a search on a binary tree (which is what map uses) - and hence there is virtually no difference between the two. 3) Real numbers are irrelevant (i.e. platform specific), but the percentages are significant, the tree above can be more than three times quicker than any of the other approaches - I wouldn't have bothered otherwise.

Comment: Hi Nim, I'd expect binary search to be faster because it has half the number of memory accesses (each binary tree node requires one access for the key and one access for the child pointer).  Is it possible that sorted vector is not inlining your comparison function?

Comment: I don't have a specific comparison function, I've implemented the `operator<` for the simple structure which I store in the vector, and this structure has the integer key, which looks like  `lhs.id < rhs.id` - I didn't check the assembler, but I'd be mightily surprised if it didn't inline the above. I'm using a very small number of elements for testing (64 to be precise) and I'd be surprised if the entire structure was not in the cache (in all the four tests).

Comment: ...and increasing the number of test items increases the the time taken (unsurprisingly - logarithmically!) With 200 items, the "optimized" tree maintains the best speed - the difference between that and `unordered_map` (which remains the same - as expected) is still three times - the unoptimized tree is half the time.

Comment: Hang on, I've just looked at your code - you've implemented a 256-way tree!  Of course that will be faster, but at much greater memory cost.  Inserting 256 items with keys 256i for i in 0..255 will occupy enough space for 64K items.

Comment: It's a little bigger than that! ;) The nodes are created only as necessary and the optimization cleans up lots of redundant nodes. The resulting three is actually quite efficient (interms of memory) whilst being very fast for lookups (iteration via visitors is no slouch either).